# Stream closed error using JWrapper

Tags: jwrapper

I have a single jar-file I'm trying to wrap with JWrapper. After a while into the process I receive this error.

Seems to have nothing with pack200 to do. I can use pack200 on the file manually, and I've excluded the file from pack200. It's whatever happens after that breaks it.

```
> java -Xmx512m -jar jwrapper-00033253833.jar jwrapper.xml
...
...
[App] Adding file to archive... (/Users/user/code/okto/build/okto.jar) (=okto.jar) (classpath=true) (dir=false) (protect=false)
[Archive] Adding file (25080185) (okto.jar) /Users/user/code/okto/build/okto.jar
[Archive] Will pack200 okto.jar
**********************************
*          BUILD FAILED          *
**********************************
** Error Trace:

java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.ensureOpen(ZipInputStream.java:67)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:116)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.getNextEntry(JarInputStream.java:142)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.getNextJarEntry(JarInputStream.java:179)
    at utils.jarbuilder.utils.JarClassVersionChecker.processJarEntry(JarClassVersionChecker.java:72)
```

Answer (score 0):

this looks like an issue with the okto.jar file.  Could you check if it is valid (open it with a zip program) and try recreating it using some other method?

Could you also check that the path to the file is correct (/Users/user/code/okto/build/okto.jar)

Comment: Works just fine to `java -jar okto.jar` or `jar -xf okto.jar`. The path is correct (removed personal info for SO). Works with install4j, but given its pricing it's not an option.